# How do I improve my logic to read and write variable values to a file?

Tags: bash, file, shell, variables

I wrote to functions in shell script to read and write variable settings from/to a file. I am wondering if there is a cleaner way to do this. I especially don't like the bit where I delete the existing match for a write and then rewrite at the end of the file. Is there a better way to do this? Thanks.

```
fnReadTestSetting()
{
#$1 is the variable to be read from the testsettings.ini file
grep $1 $MAIN_FOLDER/testsettings.ini >$MAIN_FOLDER/temp.ini
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    sed -i "s|$1=||" $MAIN_FOLDER/temp.ini
    TEST_VALUE=`cat $MAIN_FOLDER/temp.ini`
    export $1=$TEST_VALUE
fi
rm $MAIN_FOLDER/temp.ini
return
}


fnWriteTestSetting()
{
#$1 is the variable and value to be written to the testsettings.ini file in the format VARIABLE_NAME=VALUE
if [ ! -e $MAIN_FOLDER/testsettings.ini ]; then
    touch $MAIN_FOLDER/testsettings.ini
fi
SETTING_NAME=`echo $1 | awk -F = '{print $1}'`
grep $SETTING_NAME $MAIN_FOLDER/testsettings.ini &>/dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    sed -i "/^$SETTING_NAME/d" $MAIN_FOLDER/testsettings.ini
    echo "$1" >> $MAIN_FOLDER/testsettings.ini

else
    echo "$1" >> $MAIN_FOLDER/testsettings.ini
fi
return
}
```

Comment: You may wish to use `${string#substring}` to strip the shortest match of `$substring` from front of `$string`, rather than spawning `awk` to strip off the `VARIABLE=` bit; some small details here: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/refcards.html

Comment: I tried this for the read:  
 LINE=`grep $1 testsettings.ini`;  
 KEY=$1"=";  
 VALUE=${LINE#$KEY};  
 export $1=$VALUE;  
But it failed when I pass IP to the function with the value IP_ADDRESS=10.0.0.1 written to the testsettings.ini

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have made some improvements:

You can use a single sed for reading a setting. This saves writing to a tmp file. Not sure why you were trying to export $1.

```
fnReadTestSetting()
{
  #$1 is the variable to be read from the testsettings.ini file
  sed -n "s/^$1=\(.*$\)/\1/p" $MAIN_FOLDER/testsettings.ini 
}
```

For writing, you don't need to touch the file if it doesn't exist, because it will be created anyway. You don't need awk for finding the setting name. You can also place grep as the condition in your if-statement instead of explicitly checking its exit code. Use a single sed for the replacement (instead of deleting and echoing).

```
fnWriteTestSetting()
{
  #$1 is the variable and value to be written to the testsettings.ini file in the format VARIABLE_NAME=VALUE
  SETTING_NAME=${1%%=*}
  if grep -sq "^${SETTING_NAME}=" $MAIN_FOLDER/testsettings.ini
  then
    sed -i "s/^${SETTING_NAME}=.*$/$1/" $MAIN_FOLDER/testsettings.ini
  else
    echo "$1" >> $MAIN_FOLDER/testsettings.ini
  fi
  return
}
```

Update:

`%%=*` deletes everything after the `=`. For more info on the `%%` operator take a look at the [string manipulation guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html):

> `${string%%substring}` Deletes longest
>   match of $substring from back of
>   $string.

Comment: Some questions 1) sed returns an exit status of 0 whether or not there is a match for $1. Do you think there is a better way to check whether variable is defined in the file without grepping for the "variable=" in the file? 2) Could you explain how SETTING_NAME=${1%%=*} works? Never seen this before. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know what it's being used for, but the `export` sets the value of the variable name which is held in `$1`. `declare` can't be used since that would make the variable local to the function and `eval` has security risks, as you know. `a=':;pwd;: '; eval $a=foo` evaluates the `pwd` (which could have been something malicious). `declare` and `export` would produce errors and are thus safer. The just-released Bash 4.2 has `declare -g` for declaring global variables inside functions. I had not seen this `export` trick before. One side effect is that in some cases exporting may be undesirable.

Answer (score 0):

There's really no need to use `sed -i` on a temp file, since you can just use sed to return the string that you're setting to a variable anyway. Also, I don't believe your regex accounts for space on either side of the equals sign, which is often allowed in .ini files ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file ). The regex is still pretty clean, and not writing to temp files is much cleaner, as it makes the read function non-side-effecting.